# How to make a list of values based on value count in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe like this

```
   name
    a
    s
    d
    a
    s
    d
    f
    a
    s
    a
    s
```

I need to finally get the top 3 values based on value count.I did got value counts. I used,`data2['name'].value_counts(sort=True,ascending=False)`.
But instead of value count, I need those top 3 name values. ie,

```
[a,s,d]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) has default parameters `sort=True` and `ascending=False`, so should be omitted. Then filter `index` values by indexing and convert to `list`:

```
L = data2['name'].value_counts().index[:3].tolist()
print (L)
['a', 's', 'd']
```

Another solution:

```
from collections import Counter
L = [i for i, j in Counter(data2['name']).most_common(3)]
print (L)
['a', 's', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Series.nlargest`, so sorting arguments won't matter:

```
data2['name'].value_counts().nlargest(3).index
```

Comment: `value_counts()` sorting by default, so `nlargest` is not necessary here